# snowflake generic etl process not working

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

All,

I am trying to create an generic copy command into snowflake using a JavaScript procedure

```
var my_sql_command = "select * from vw_etl_src order by 2 asc";
-- sql will return something to this effect 
-- copy into etl_db.eod_data from @myint_stage/cm01jun2022bhav.csv.gz;
var statement1 = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: my_sql_command} );
-- get the result into a variable and 
                                     while (result_set1.next())  {
                                        var res = result_set1.getColumnValue(1);
  -- I was hoping to executing the copy command 
                                        snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: res
                                                                 } ).execute();
                                        }
```

I am calling this and although it runs no data is loaded . I did truncate the table manually.
I have set EXECUTE AS OWNER.

Any pointers

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason for this block not to work. All I see is, that result_set1 is not defined, but it's probably because you didn't share the whole script.

```
var result_set1 = statement1.execute();
```

You also didn't share any errors, so I assume that JS procedure is completed without any error. In this case, check the query history to see how your COPY command was executed:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-history.html#overview-of-features

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html

You may also want to check COPY_HISTORY:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/copy_history.html

Comment: I missed this part var result_set1 = statement1.execute(); Thanks

Comment: @nick_leeson was it about the missing assignment? Is your question answered? 
 if so, can you mark the answer as correct?